# How to center my navlinks in my navigation

Tags: html, css

I'm sure it's a very simple fix and I've gone wrong somewhere. I haven't added the actual links yet as you can see.

CSS:

```
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-top: 1px solid #3f3f3f;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    background-color: #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 17, 17, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px -1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 17, 17, 1);
    box-shadow:         0px -1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 17, 17, 1);
}

 nav li {
     float: left;
     margin: 0 auto;
 }

 nav li a {
     display: block;
     color: #ededed !important;
     font-family:'Tahoma','Verdana','Arial',sans-serif;
     font-size: 1.1em;
     padding: 17px 19px;
     text-decoration: none;
 }

 nav li:hover {
     background-color: #353535;
 }

 nav li a:hover {
     color: #49b2c8 !important;
     -webkit-transition: color 0.4s ease-in;
     -moz-transition: color 0.4s ease-in;
     -o-transition: color 0.4s ease-in;
     -ms-transition: color 0.4s ease-in;
     transition: color 0.4s ease-in;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
     <ul>
         <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Help</a></li>
         <li><a href="">About</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Staff</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
         <li><a href="">News</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Search</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Shop</a></li>
     </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
nav {
  text-align: center;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav li a {
  display: block;
  /* The rest of your code here */
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, didnt work for some reason

Comment: Ahh it was due to the float: left; in nav li - thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

If u want to centralise the links as a while towards the center of parent i.e. `<ul></ul>`
make `li` as `inline-block` and give `text-align: center` in `ul`. Remove `float: left;`

```
ul {
 text-align: center;
 ....
}
ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 /* float: left; */ 
 ....
}
```

If u want each link to be center of `li` set a width for `li` and put `text-align: center` for `li`. Since you have 8 links, to equally divide width, set width for li as 12.5%

```
li {
 text-align: center;
 width: 12.5%;
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip: Using the pseudo class  `:hover`  will automatically override the initial color you set for the nav links. Therefore, your use of `!important` is unnecessary.

Check out this page for additional info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity